# Google drive dredit token error

Tags: google-drive-api

I truncate the users table and now i can't run the app, always this error at logs:

> [15-May-2012 22:56:58] Error when authenticating and authorizing user:
>   Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message: 'invalid_grant'
>
> [15-May-2012 22:56:59] Error when authenticating and authorizing user:
>   Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message: 'invalid_grant'
>
> [15-May-2012 22:56:59] Error when authenticating and authorizing user:
>   Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message: 'invalid_grant'
>
> [15-May-2012 22:57:00] Error retrieving user from DB or updating
>   refresh token: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048
>   Column 'refresh_token' cannot be null
>
> [15-May-2012 22:57:00] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception
>   'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint
>   violation: 1048 Column 'refresh_token' cannot be null' in
>   /var/www/drivecrypt/www/auth_handler.php:214
>
> Stack trace:
>
> #0 /var/www/drivecrypt/www/auth_handler.php(214):
>   PDOStatement->execute()
>
> #1 /var/www/drivecrypt/www/auth_handler.php(244):
>   AuthHandler->CreateUserInDb(Object(Userinfo), NULL)
>
> #2 /var/www/drivecrypt/www/auth_handler.php(293):
>   AuthHandler->GetUser(Object(Userinfo), NULL)
>
> #3 /var/www/drivecrypt/www/index.php(48): AuthHandler->VerifyAuth()
>   #4 {main}
>
> thrown in /var/www/drivecrypt/www/auth_handler.php on line 214

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

Column 'refresh_token' cannot be null

Comment: Yeah i read,but why is null? the first time you start the app is the same situation, the table is empty and you need to insert the value, why now is null? is not the same situation? why truncate crash the auth?

Comment: I change access_type=online to access_type=offline at const FULL_AUTH_URL and all work again.