# Google drive oauth token error

Tags: google-drive-api

I was running dredit example,the first time you start the app the sql table is empty and the app insert a value, all run ok, but I truncate the table and now 'refresh_token' is null and the app crash. Why now is null? is not the same situation as firts time run? why truncate crash the auth?

> [15-May-2012 22:56:59] Error when authenticating and authorizing user:
>   Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message: 'invalid_grant'
>
> [15-May-2012 22:57:00] Error retrieving user from DB or updating
>   refresh token: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048
>   Column 'refresh_token' cannot be null
>
> [15-May-2012 22:57:00] PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint
>   violation: 1048 Column 'refresh_token' cannot be null' in
>   /var/www/drivecrypt/www/auth_handler.php:214
>
> Stack trace:
>
> #0 /var/www/drivecrypt/www/auth_handler.php(214): PDOStatement->execute()
>
> #1 /var/www/drivecrypt/www/auth_handler.php(244): AuthHandler->CreateUserInDb(Object(Userinfo), NULL)
>
> #2 /var/www/drivecrypt/www/auth_handler.php(293): AuthHandler->GetUser(Object(Userinfo), NULL)
>
> #3 /var/www/drivecrypt/www/index.php(48): AuthHandler->VerifyAuth() #4 {main}
>
> thrown in /var/www/drivecrypt/www/auth_handler.php on line 214

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google drive dredit token error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610016/google-drive-dredit-token-error)

Comment: Could you explain why you truncated the table? And what you did exactly (where did you truncate it?)

Comment: I am also having trouble with this, I attempt to authenticate and I never get a refresh token from the API, at all.

Answer (score 0):

You should catch the exception in AuthHandler->GetUserFromDb and return null to AuthHandler->GetUser. However, by doing so, it will create a new user entry in session with an empty refresh token and subsequent requests will fail with a 401.

To address this issue, you need to make sure that $_SESSION['credentials'] is unset when you reach https://code.google.com/p/google-drive-sdk-samples/source/browse/php/auth_handler.php#335, so that the user will be redirected to the OAuth authorization page and grant access again in order to request a new refresh token.